# How to catch left click event for coordinates MFC Picture Control

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to follow an example to register click events so I can grab coordinates for my mandelbrot experiment. I am trying to get the x and y coordinates of the output picture box image that is created when the mandelbrot is compiled. The issue is that it does not recognise `UWM_ON_TNB_LCLICKED` and `UWM_ON_TNB_RCLICKED`.

I followed the example word by word but I'm not sure what I am supposed to put in place of `UWM_ON_TNB_LCLICKED` and `UWM_ON_TNB_RCLICKED`. The picture box where I want the user to click in is called `IDC_BMP`. I am trying to only get the coordinates within the picturebox `IDC_BMP` so that I can apply my zoom.

[image]

**mbrotDlg.h**

```
protected:

**afx_msg LRESULT OnTnbLClicked(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /* lParam  */);
afx_msg LRESULT OnTnbRClicked(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /* lParam */);**
DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()

public:
afx_msg void OnBnClickedBtnCompile();
afx_msg void OnBnClickedBtnTest();
```

**mbrotDlg.cpp**

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMandelbrotExperimentDlg, CDialogEx)
ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTNCOMPILE, &CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnBnClickedBtnCompile) //Start Monitoring Button
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnBnClickedBtnTest) //Start Monitoring Button
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(UWM_ON_TNB_LCLICKED, OnTnbLClicked)
ON_REGISTERED_MESSAGE(UWM_ON_TNB_RCLICKED, OnTnbRClicked)
```

Functions:

```
LRESULT CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnTnbLClicked(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /* lParam  */) { return 0; }
LRESULT CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnTnbRClicked(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /* lParam */) { return 0; }
```

I have tried the following but the program just crashes on startup. It crashes on the `PreTranlateMessage` function.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00B8D789 in Mandelbrot Experiment.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00602F20).

**mbrotDlg.cpp**

```
BOOL CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class
if (pMsg->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN && GetDlgItem(IDC_BMP)->GetSafeHwnd() == 
pMsg->hwnd)
{
    CPoint point(pMsg->pt);
    ScreenToClient(&point);

    OnLButtonDown(pMsg->wParam, point);   
}

return CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);

}


 void CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnLButtonDown(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
 {
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

CRect rect;
m_picture.GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(&rect);
if (rect.PtInRect(point))
{
    // Do something
}

CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnLButtonDown(nFlags, point);
}
```

I have got it almost working, when I hover the mouse over the preview image it executes the event on the picture control. However I have an error in this line of the code (indicated in comments):

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStaticSub, CStatic)
ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()


void CStaticSub::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{

    ScreenToClient(&point);
    CString str;
    str.Format("[%d, %d]", point.x, point.y); // Error on this line
    this->GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT10)->SetWindowText(str);

    CStatic::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
```

}

If I set `str` to `"Hello"` I see it appear in one of the edit boxes when I hover over the picture.

Comment: Why do you need to use registered messages instead of just `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`? Registered messages are used for triggering custom events, and mostly between different applications (both applications register the same message). What makes you thinking that these registered messages are in any way related to mouse input?

Comment: I'll stick with it and eventually figure it out, thanks for the useful input.

Comment: You need to stop using MFC until you have a working understanding of the Windows API. This question is asking about a solution rather than the issue. The solution appears to be based on assumptions that aren't true. Someone that understands how the system works will not be able to follow the reasoning that led you to that solution.

Comment: I'm not asking for a solution, I am trying lots of things. To learn is to ask questions, I can't understand the Windows API without trying the thing in the first place! Thanks anyway, will eventually figure it out. I'm not one of those people who can read a book and understand it, I have to try for myself and keep trying (which I am doing)

Comment: You cannot learn the Windows API by throwing in a second API into the mix which you do not understand either. Stop using MFC and learn the Windows API in isolation first. Once you are familiar with the Windows API you can start learning C++. Only after you have mastered both of these do you stand a chance of actually understanding MFC, no sooner. Your question history strongly suggests that you aren't making *any* progress.

Comment: I know MFC is a million years old. But its a steep learning curve and the way I learn things is by throwing myself in the deep end and with the help from forums (And Google) learning my way through it.. It's just the way I learn things. I'm not a genius, just someone who has an interest in C++. Thanks.

Comment: As I said: You aren't learning. You have made *zero* progress in the time you have used this site. You are blindly trying things at random, without knowing what you are doing or why you are doing it. You may think that this is your personal way of learning, but it isn't. You are struggling with 3 separate areas (Windows API, C++, MFC) and never understand, which domain you are in. This isn't going to work out however much you wish it would.

Comment: OK IInspectable, You've said what you needed to get of your chest, I hope that it brings you great happiness. I will keep on trying to figure it out.

Comment: The problem my friend is that the mouse move is triggered multiple times. So you probably have to set a variable to detect if you need to set it and then only update your control the once. Or set a timer and update the controls every x milliseconds based on current mouse pos. Otherwise it is gonna choke.

Comment: Maybe `WM_MOUSEENTER` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` are alternatives: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24748173/2287576 But it seems you have a working solution.

Comment: I admit that I never really learned the *Windows API* as such. I learned with good books and examples *MFC*. By learning those concepts I kind of automatically picked on much of the underlying *Windows API*. But I could never write a native Windows API derived app and I have been coding in MFC with 1990s.

Comment: I do have one question. The mandelbrot.bmp is set to 800x600 pixels. The picturebox is scaled to 300x300. What math would I use to calculate the coordinates from the picturebox and scale up to 800x600? Or I do not need to? Thanks.

Comment: That is another question my friend.

Comment: ha! ok, no problem.

Comment: [Why is there no WM_MOUSEENTER message?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031013-00/?p=42193) Plot spoiler: The answer would be obvious, if you did in fact know the Windows API. No matter the books you read, you cannot possibly understand a framework when you do not know the system it wraps. Particularly true with a leaky abstraction like MFC.

Answer (score -1):

To make this work, I created a class derived from `CStatic` as shown below:

**CStaticSub.h**

```
#pragma once
 #include <afxdialogex.h>

class CStaticSub :
public CStatic
{
    public:
    CStatic m_pic;

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    afx_msg void OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
};
```

I added a public `CStatic` variable called `m_pic` which will be used by my picture control on my main dialog.

**CStaticSub.cpp**

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "CStaticSub.h"
#include "Mandelbrot Experiment.h"
#include "Mandelbrot ExperimentDlg.h"


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CStaticSub, CStatic)
ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CStaticSub::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    ScreenToClient(&point);
    CString strx;
    CString stry;
    strx.Format(_T("%d"), point.x);
    stry.Format(_T("%d"), point.y);
    this->GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT10)->SetWindowText(strx);
    this->GetParent()->GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT11)->SetWindowText(stry);

    CStatic::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);

  }
```

Then in the main dialog I then subclassed the picture control:

**Mandelbrot Experiment.h**

```
class CMandelbrotExperimentDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    // Construction
public:
   CMandelbrotExperimentDlg(CWnd* pParent = nullptr);   // standard constructor
   CStaticSub m_pic;
```

Then in the main dialog .cpp I created the function that would fire on mousemove or mouseclick as shown below:

**Mandelbrot ExperimentDlg.cpp**

```
void mynamespace::CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{   
    //Get the Picture Control's Rect To check
    CRect rect;
    m_pic.GetWindowRect(rect);
    ScreenToClient(&rect);

    //Store The Cursor Position
    CPoint pt;
    GetCursorPos(&pt);

    //Make it as LPARAM and send it
    LPARAM lp = MAKELPARAM(pt.x, pt.y);

    //If the mouse is hovering over the picture control..
    if (rect.PtInRect(point))
    {
        m_pic.SendMessage(WM_MOUSEMOVE, 0, lp);
    }

    CDialog::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

Finally I added the message event

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMandelbrotExperimentDlg, CDialogEx)
ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTNCOMPILE, &CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnBnClickedBtnCompile) 
//Start Monitoring Button
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CMandelbrotExperimentDlg::OnBnClickedBtnTest) 

//THIS ONE!
ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE(OnMouseMove)


END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

This could be adapted for mouse clicks also. I felt that hover was better in the end.